# How do I enable breakpoints/debugging of MSpec tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, mspec

It seems MSpec/Visual Studio ignores any breakpoints I set on test code. How do I enable breakpoints when running an MSpec test?

Answer (score 0):

When you run tests in Visual Studio, by default they run without attaching the debugger (same as ctrl+F5 for your application).

Go to the test explorer window (Test->Windows->Test Explorer) and right click your test to debug it, this will start the test run with the attached debugger and will stop on breakpoints.

[image]